# when the user logged in. its not redirecting to comments page . return redirect (''comments) need id think in def..login_user in views.py

Tags: django, django-views

NoReverseMatch at /login/
reverse for 'comments' with no arguments not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['comments/(?p[0-9]+)\z', '\ comments/(?p[0-9]+)/\z']

155. return redirect ('comments') //this line  is highliting error. how to provide id argument to ('comments') in login_user in views.py?
     code in below.. please respond!

def login_user(request,):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
return redirect('/')

```
    if request.method=='POST':
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('pwd')
        user = authenticate(request,email=email,password=password)
       
    
        if user is not None:
         login(request,user)
         return redirect ('comments')//this line is showing error i think//
 
        else:
             return HttpResponse('details wrong')
   
    return render(request,'events/login.html')
```

@login_required(login_url="/login")

def comments(request,id):

```
 if request.method=='POST':
   rating=request.POST['rating']
   review_title=request.POST['review_title']
   review=request.POST['review']
   good=request.POST['good']
   bad=request.POST['bad']
   product=Product.objects.get(pk=id)
   user=request.user
   mydata=Post(men=user,product=product, rating=rating,review_title=review_title,review=review,positive_points=good,Negative_points=bad)
   mydata.save()
 return render(request,'events/comments.html')
```

path(' comments/int:id/', views. comments, name='comments'),

path('login/', views. login_user, name='login' ),

Answer (score 0):

try this

please correct your URL syntax

**int:id not int:id**

Ref https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#example

```
path('comments/<int:id>/',views.comments,name="comments"), 
path('login/',views.login_user,name='login' ),
```

Comment: path('comments/<int:id>/',views.comments,name="comments"), it is ok bro. but it showing...155. return redirect ('comments ')// is highliting error in login_user in views.py   ... so redirect comments need id argument i think , so how to provide id to comments in login_user in views.py . can you please respond bro?